# A word for something that's done only half-consciously

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, connotation

In writing fiction, I find myself using the word "absentmindedly" a lot, but I don't think it's really the word I'm looking for. I'm not looking so much something done in a *distracted* manner, but something done sort of half-consciously, without really thinking about it. Not habitual either, but perhaps *almost* instinctual.

For instance:

> As James watched the other girl climb higher, he shuddered to think of his own sister being in such danger, and put his arm *absentmindedly* around her.

What I'm trying to relate is that he wasn't making a conscious move to comfort or embrace his sister, he just did it without thinking.

Comment: You probably shouldn't ask an adverb or adjective to do so much work for you. If you mean to say somebody wasn't paying full attention, say so. Spend an extra sentence. Don't expect your readers to fill in for you.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with " . . . as he almost un-consciously put his arm around her."  Or, start a new sentence, as John Lawler suggests.  "Without thinking he put his arm around her."

Comment: Though I agree with @JohnLawler here, I would also suggest "mechanically" as another synonym that might work in similar contexts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word ***instinctively*** fits here.

> As James watched the other girl climb higher, he shuddered to think of his own sister being in such danger, and instinctively put his arm around her.

The action is done without thinking about it, as an innate reaction to thinking of the danger and protecting his sister.

Comment: Thanks. I had initially dismissed that (absentmindedly, perhaps), but now that I actually see it in use, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

My initial thought is ***sub-consciously*** would be a suitable choice.

I prefer that to *almost un-consciously* suggested in some of the comments.